# Toggle Menu don't work only with Firefox for Android

Tags: jquery, css

I have menu responsive for mobile with my site www.informarea.it.

Since few days if I tap on toggle menu in browser Firefox don't happen nothing, i must to zoom for to see activate toggle menu and then tap, so work perfectly. Very Strange.

On Chrome and Internet Explorer mobile work perfectly, I have problem only in Firefox for mobile.

What may have happened? Someone can help me.

Comment: can you opst code please?

Comment: the problem have it also the site that created the script...in this page http://www.meanthemes.com/plugins/meanmenu/

Comment: Ok solved with this step: I removed firefox and I installed new version Firefox..